# Merging 2 MP4 Files With the cat Command

Tags: macos, bash, unix, cat

I am on OS X 10.10 and I am trying to merge 2 MP4 files using the `cat` command. I thought that I could do this using the `cat` command, but it seems not to be working. When I merge the two files together and wrote it to a 3rd file, the 3rd file simply had the contents of the first file (when I opened it up using QuickTime). From what I understand, the `cat` command is simply copying and pasting the plain text from the first file to the third file then the plain text from the second file to the third file (appending it), but QuickTime only will recognize the first part of this. **Is there any way to use the `cat` command to get around this?**

Comment: Related in U&L: [Is it possible to merge video files using `cat`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/43896/40596). In general, no.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're getting confused with `mp4box`'s `-cat` option, using which you can execute the following:

`mp4box -add 1.mp4 -cat 2.mp4 -cat 3.mp4 merged.mp4`

In order to merge ***1.mp4***, ***2.mp4*** and ***3.mp4*** to ***merged.mp4***

Otherwise, `cat - concatenate files and print on the standard output` does not support this kind of behavior.

Answer (score 0):

No. `cat` does not manipulate the metadata of the files at all, so there is no way to merge non-text files together using it unless the file format is already designed to work with simple concatenation.

Comment: Can I open it in a hex editor and delete the header of the second file?

Comment: Only if the file format is designed that way. Most are not. Try using a tool actually designed to merge video files together.